# O que exatamente é hipertexto?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, terminologia

Pesquisei e não encontrei uma resposta sobre isso: CSS é considerado hipertexto?

Tenho essa dúvida pois PHP, que é pré-processador de hipertexto, também pode pré-processar CSS e até mesmo JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hipertexto é texto comum com outras informações agregadas. Segundo a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipertexto):

> **Hipertexto** é o termo que remete a um texto ao qual se agregam outros conjuntos de informação na forma de blocos de textos, palavras, imagens ou sons, cujo acesso se dá através de referências específicas, no meio digital denominadas hiperlinks, ou simplesmente links.

A ideia de hipertexto não está restrita ao meio digital, contudo, um simples livro com notas de rodapé<sup>[1]</sup> pode ser considerado hipertexto. HTML é a linguagem mais comum para se expressar hipertexto hoje em dia, mas há outras, eu diria por exemplo que [Markdown](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (a mesma linguagem usada nas perguntas e respostas do StackOverflow) e [BBCode](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) (muito usada em fóruns de discussão) também são hipertexto. Estendendo-se o conceito para outras mídias - como imagens, vídeos, etc - chegamos ao que é chamado de [hipermídia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiperm%C3%ADdia) (pense por exemplo em vídeos no YouTube com anotações, legendas em vários idiomas, ou links externos dentro do próprio vídeo).

Sobre CSS (e JavaScript), eu diria que não, não é uma forma de hipertexto. Ninguém (nenhum leitor humano) consome CSS pelo seu conteúdo em si, ele está sempre modificando a aparência de um outro conteúdo, principal. Da mesma forma, uma linguagem de programação foi feita para ser executada, não lida, e outros formatos *baseados em texto* (como XML ou JSON) têm o propósito de armazenar dados estruturados, para serem consumidos por outros programas, não pelo usuário final.

O fato de PHP ser [atualmente] um "acrônimo recursivo" pra "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor", isso não significa que ele está restrito a preprocessar hipertexto - trata-se de uma linguagem de programação de propósito geral, capaz de executar inclusive fora do contexto de um *webserver* e lidar com dados de natureza arbitrária (inclusive dados binários). Mas como seu "ponto forte" é gerar hipertexto, as pessoas logo perceberam que ele era capaz também de gerar outros tipos de arquivo baseados em texto, daí seu uso para esses fins.

---

[1]: como esta.

Comment: Só um detalhe, se for levar ao pé da letra esta definição de hipertexto do wikipédia em português está meio errada (foi por isso que usei a definição em inglês como referência). 
Hipertexto refere-se apenas à texto e nada mais. Quando inclui-se "sons e imagens" já estamos falando de hipermídia, e não de hipertexto.

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa Acho que você tem razão, embora a parte que diz "cujo acesso se dá através de referências específicas" é meio ambígua pra mim (se um texto faz referência para algo que não é texto ele deixa de ser hipertexto?).

Comment: Bem, eu já não vejo esta parte como sendo ambígua. Nesse caso interpretei "referências específicas" como sendo o hiperlink em si. Na minha opinião (baseado no que li), sim, se o texto faz referência para algo que não é texto  - outra página, contendo ou não imagens, áudio, etc - entao ele deixa de ser considerado hipertexto.
De qualquer forma, isso tudo é muito subjetivo e muitas opiniões diferentes surgem em tópicos como esses...

Mas acho interessante discutir.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com [w3.org](http://W3.org/whatis.html):

> Hipertexto é um texto que não está limitado a ser sempre linear.
>
> Hipertexto é qualquer texto que contenha *links* para outros textos. O termo foi foi cunhado por Ted Nelson em 1965.

Wikipédia em inglês [Hypertext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext):

> Hipertexto é qualquer texto mostrado na tela de um computador ou qualquer outro dispositivo eletrônico e que contém referências ([Hiperlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlinks)) à outro texto que pode ser acessado imediatamente pelo leitor(...)

Em outras palavras, hipertexto é qualquer texto com referências externas, estejam elas apontando para um diretório local ou na web.

Agora, se CSS é hipertexto, bem, penso que não, mas vou deixar que alguém mais experiente responda. Sobre o PHP, penso que ele serve para gerar hipertexto (entre outras coisas), mas também não acredito que por si só possa ser considerado hipertexto.

Me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

Comment: Não vejo porquê CSS seria hipertexto, nem [texto](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/texto) ele é ;)